# Making a model of an item from a list model in wicket

Tags: java, list, wicket

Wicket Version: 6.14

I have a

```
LoadableDetachableModel<List<Foo>>
```

I am trying to use the model with a wizard but each page of the wizard will use a single item of the list.

I want to get a model of each in the list and change the model between each screen in the wizard.

Ideally I could do something like this:

```
PropertyModel<Foo> fooItemModel = new PropertyModel<Foo>(fooItems, "get(0)");
```

One other idea I have had is to roll my own ListItemModel and make it take an

```
IModel<List<?>>
```

instead of a ListView.

```
public ListItemModel(final ListView<T> listView, final int index)
{
    this.listView = listView;
    this.index = index;
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.wicket.model.IModel#getObject()
 */
@Override
public T getObject()
{
    return listView.getModelObject().get(index);
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.wicket.model.IModel#setObject(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public void setObject(T object)
{
    listView.getModelObject().set(index, object);
}
```

Any advice is appreciated in advanced

Comment: What do you want to add to the List? Just simple strings and numbers or objects? And if they are objects, are they Serializable?

Comment: The number of steps in the wizard is dependent on how many items I retrieve from the database so it is dynamic. Each page represents a single item in my model so I needed a way to pull out that single item for the single step in the wizard. The ElementModel I created below works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by making my own model similar to ListItemModel and using the page index to determine which model to pull out of the main model.

```
public class ElementModel<T> implements IModel<T>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The list model */
    private IModel<List<T>> listModel;

    /** The list item's index */
    private final int index;

    /**
     * Construct
     * 
     * @param listModel
     *            The list model
     * @param index
     *            The index of this model
     */
    public ElementModel(final IModel<List<T>> listModel, final int index)
    {
        this.listModel = listModel;
        this.index = index;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.model.IModel#getObject()
     */
    @Override
    public T getObject()
    {
        return listModel.getObject().get(index);
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.model.IModel#setObject(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public void setObject(T object)
    {
        listModel.getObject().set(index, object);
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.model.IDetachable#detach()
     */
    @Override
    public void detach()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wizard libraries already exist that would be much easier to implement rather than trying to write your own.  You should take a look at Wicket's built-in [Wizard](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/wizard/Wizard.html) component (examples with source [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/wizard)), or [JQuery's](http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/wizard/DefaultWizardPage).

Comment: I am not trying to write my own I am using wicket's wizard library "org.apache.wicket.extensions.wizard.Wizard"